# REST API to Excel integration Azure Logic Apps

Tags: excel, azure-logic-apps, rest, incremental-load

I have data extracted through REST API from one of my applications and store it in a spreadsheet. I am using Azure Logic apps to extract data based on the date range for incremental loading everyday. In worst case, if I run the workflow twice in a single day, the data might be duplicated in the target spreadsheet. Is there a way to keep a check to avoid inserting or update the existing data in the target side ?

Comment: Could you  please share a screenshot of your `Azure logic app`?

Comment: If it is based on a date range, is the extraction of duplicate data due to date overlap?

Comment: In an incremental load, always store the last run time and ensure your logic app doesn't pull records before the last run time.